# What are the options supported in CSIDriver kubernetes object

Tags: kubernetes, csi-driver

https://kubernetes-csi.github.io/docs/csi-driver-object.html gives details on CSIDriver object. Is there a way we can customize the parameters in this object. I tested but it fails with

```
Error from server (BadRequest): error when creating "csidriver.yaml": CSIDriver in version "v1" cannot be handled as a CSIDriver: strict decoding error: unknown field "spec.test"
```

[ test was the extra param I added ]

So what I am looking for is , any way we can get CSIDriver supported capabilities from this object.

Comment: are your queries addressed if you are still having some queries let us know here so that we can assist you...

Answer (score 0):

In this [blog](https://bluexp.netapp.com/blog/cvo-blg-kubernetes-csi-basics-of-csi-volumes-and-how-to-build-a-csi-driver) written by Yifat Perry, she has given a detailed explanation of Container Storage Interface(CSI), she has also explained how to build new CSI Driver plugins for your storage systems.

> Kubernetes CSI is a Kubernetes-specific implementation of the Container Storage Interface (CSI). The CSI specification provides a standard that enables connectivity between storage systems and container orchestration (CO) platforms. It is the foundation of Kubernetes storage management.  
> The CSI standard determines how arbitrary blocks and file storage systems are exposed to workloads on containerization systems like Kubernetes. Third-party storage vendors can use CSI to build plugins and deploy them to enable Kubernetes to work with new storage systems, without having to edit the core code of Kubernetes.

Go through "Build your own CSI Driver for Kubernetes" section in the blog provided above for more information on how to build CSI Driver from scratch or to add a custom CSI Driver object and each storage vendor has their own CSI Driver Plugins, go through their official documentations for adding a custom CSI Driver object.

Comment: Thanks for the link. But what I am looking for is some API which gives all the capabilities supported by that CSI Driver

Comment: @ambikanair I have gone through many docs and resources, but I'm unable to find such an API. If I come across any such API I will ping here.

Comment: Thank you @Kranthiveer Dontineni for your time and effort.